# is the connection/cursor object automatically closed in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I do a `engine=create_engine(...)` and then `engine.execute(SQL)` does SQLAlchemy manage the closing of connection/cursor with the execute statement or is it something I need to do myself?

I've looked at the [`execute`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) method but it wasn't clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, from the bits of code that you show, you are looking at the wrong documentation for execute.
The right doc for execute from what you show to be your code is the following:
[engine.execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute).
Here it says

> The returned ResultProxy is flagged such that when the ResultProxy is exhausted and its underlying cursor is closed, the Connection created here will also be closed, which allows its associated DBAPI connection resource to be returned to the connection pool.

You are using a
[connectionless execution](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#dbengine-implicit)

and you can see the example presented there:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///file.db')
result = engine.execute(users_table.select())
for row in result:
    # ....
result.close()
```

So the `result` variable is a `ResultProxy` and you can see that in the example that is explicitly closed.
The documentation [ResultProxy.close()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.close) tells exactly what gets closed, and your case seems to belong to connectionless execution so once closed, also the connection will be closed.
These bits of the doc on close are particularly important:

> This closes out the underlying DBAPI cursor corresponding to the statement execution, if one is still present. Note that the DBAPI cursor is automatically released when the ResultProxy exhausts all available rows. ResultProxy.close() is generally an optional method except in the case when discarding a ResultProxy that still has additional rows pending for fetch.
> In the case of a result that is the product of connectionless execution, the underlying Connection object is also closed, which releases DBAPI connection resources.

I suggest to also read carefully the notes about changes in the 1.0.0 version:

> Changed in version 1.0.0: - the ResultProxy.close() method has been separated out from the process that releases the underlying DBAPI cursor resource. The “auto close” feature of the Connection now performs a so-called “soft close”, which releases the underlying DBAPI cursor, but allows the ResultProxy to still behave as an open-but-exhausted result set; the actual ResultProxy.close() method is never called. *It is still safe to discard a ResultProxy that has been fully exhausted without calling this method*.

I think now you should have all the material and decide what fit your case.
Personally, even if it says the close is optional in most cases except that case mentioned, I would use it.